# Form data in URL

Tags: php

Alright, so I'm working on a script for a game right now that requires a user's ID and user's API key in the url. What I am trying to do is get the ID in the URL without ?= etc.
http://example.com/user/[MyID]?selections=networth&key=[MyKey]
Basically, in the MyID and MyKey sections, there is a numerical value. I need to create a form that asks for the ID and api key and puts them directly in their respective locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a simple form like this...

```
<form action='proccess.php' method='post'>
    <input name='id' />
    <input name='key' />
    <input type="submit" value="Create URL">
</form>
```

Then on `proccess.php` retrieve the data like so...

```
$id  = $_POST['id'];
$key = $_POST['key'];
```

At this point you can do what you need to with the `$id` and `$key`

Answer (score 0):

well if you mean you want to get rid of the "?" in the link there is a trick that I use and is to name the variable using "/" so if you want to name a variable "sections" you can name it "/sections"